Nested for loop in blazor - index variable has maximum value?
I wanted to use a nested for loop in a razor file, and use the indexes of these for loops to determine which picture to show. My code looked like this:
        @for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            <MudItem>
                @for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
                {  
                    stoel = GereserveerdeStoelen.Where(s => s.XPositionChair == i && s.YPositionChair == j).SingleOrDefault();
                    @if (stoel is null)
                    {
                        <MudImage Width="40" Src="images/chair.png" Alt="chair" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center py-8" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <MudImage Width="40" Src="images/chair_not.png" Alt="chair" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center py-8" />
                    }
                }

            </MudItem>
        }

Sadly this did not seem to work. The value of i seemed to always be 6. I could not find the problem for this exact situation, but found a similar problem with lambdas, and the solution for that worked for me too. I assign the index to a local variable, and then use that local variable.
My new code looks like this:
        @for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int local = i;
            <MudItem>
                @for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    stoel = GereserveerdeStoelen.Where(s => s.XPositionChair == local && s.YPositionChair == j).SingleOrDefault();
                    @if (stoel is null)
                    {
                        <MudImage Width="40" Src="images/chair.png" Alt="chair" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center py-8" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <MudImage Width="40" Src="images/chair_not.png" Alt="chair" Class="d-flex align-center justify-center py-8" />
                    }
                }

            </MudItem>
        }

However, I don't completely understand the issue, and why this solution works. Can someone provide an explanation?

why not use a debugger and step through your code and look at the actual values of i and j?

@UweKeim I have done this, that's how I discovered that the value of i was always 6.

I tried to reproduce this problem but could not.  I've had it happen to me before, though I don't know the exact mechanism either.  But I do know that your solution is the recommended one.

The issue you're encountering is related to how the C# compiler captures loop variables in closures.
This is a well-known problem when using variables defined in the loop within nested constructs (like lambdas or Razor code blocks).
When you use a loop variable inside a nested construct, the variable isn't just copied into that construct; instead, the construct captures a reference to the loop variable. This means that all iterations of the loop share the same variable, which leads to unexpected behavior.
In the first code snippet you provided, The variable i is captured by the Razor code block, and since the Razor code block effectively creates a closure, the captured variable's value at the time of execution will be the last value it had in the loop (which is 6 in this case).
In your second code snippet (the one that worked for you), local is a new variable that holds the current value of i for each iteration. This ensures that each iteration of the outer loop has its own unique value of local, and thus, the nested constructs capture the correct value.
You can check the Capture of outer variables and variable scope in lambda expressions and other sections, I hope they give a better picture for what I am trying to convey.
Edit
Consider the following simplified example without Razor syntax but demonstrating the same principle:
var actions = new List<Action>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine($"i: {i}, j: {j}"));
    }
}

// Execute actions
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action();
}

you would think about the result or the output to be something like:
i: 0, j: 0
i: 0, j: 1
i: 0, j: 2
i: 1, j: 0
i: 1, j: 1
etc...

but the actual output is this:
i: 3, j: 3
i: 3, j: 3
i: 3, j: 3
i: 3, j: 3
etc... you got the point

So the ultimate solution would be to capture both i and j with local variables like int localI = i; and int localJ = j;. You will eventually end up with the expected "correct" behaviour.

Could you expand on why this issue happens to the outermost loop index (i), but not the innermost (j)? Also why this issue occurs in Blazor? I get that lambda expressions are evaluated at a later point, but what about Blazor makes it capture a reference instead of the actual value?

@Tigris The issue with capturing the loop variable happens for both the outermost and innermost loop indices. However, the effect is more apparent (and critical) in the outer loop when nested loops are involved because the outer loop variable is shared across multiple iterations of the inner loop. I will edit my given answer with an example later

Very well written and explained. Nice answer.
